# What does “S” stands for in OOPS?

Tags: object-oriented, terminology

I have searched for the full form of "**OOPS**" in [Google](http://www.google.co.in/#q=What+does+S+stands+for+in+OOPS), but unfortunately, there are many ambiguous answers. Some say it's "**Systems**", and some say it's "**Structure**", and some have even mentioned it as "**Synopsis**".

Can anybody please enlighten me, to find the full form of OOPS, with some proper & correct reference?

Many thanks to everyone, helping me out.

Comment: OOP = Object Oriented Programming. [Oops](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oops) on the other hand is quite different.

Comment: You might have seen it in the context of OOPSLA, an ACM research conference on Object-Oriented Programming, Systems, Languages and Applications.

Comment: Object oriented programming is not really a system but its a Programming Pattern. So According to me, OOPS has no meaning. Its just OOP.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say Object Oriented Programming System is used the most. But really, this is not widespread or known to such a degree to warrant it being a useful acronym. [This](http://www.abbreviations.com/OOPS) link is pretty cool, it's all about abbreviations. I would otherwise agree with Vineet Reynolds and say that, in practice, you should just use "OOP" and consider "OOPS" as 'oops'.

Answer (score 33):

Everywhere I look, the people that use "OOPS" are not people whose native language is English. I truly believe therefore that many developers use "OOPS" out of habit; it is done because other developers do.

I think it is important to make it clear that the term is Object Oriented Programming and the "S" is extraneous. If you search the internet for "object oriented programming system" then you will get some results but not many results.

Object Oriented Programming is a philosophy; it is improper to call it a system. A system would be something that implements the Object Oriented Programming philosophy.

Comment: Though I am not an english native speaker, calling OOP a "philosophy" sounds unfamiliar to me. I think the term "paradigm" is more established.

Comment: @DocBrown "approach" or "methodology" are more commonly used terms. "Paradigm" comes across as a I-only-know-buzzwords-beanhead. Technically, it is still correct usage - just awkward. "Philosophy" starts taking on theological overtones with potentially negative connotations being implied.  To be fair, I will acknowledge that OOP _can_ affect how you view things and does have rightful claim to being a philosophy so it's a correct term as well.  Methodology is probably the most neutral term. Sam - good observation on stating OOP that is _not_ a System.

Answer (score 3):

Up to you how highly you rate the sources below, but it's most often found with "system". However as you found out already, it's not used often, so don't use the abbreviation yourself if you want things to be clear for your audience.

> OOPS Object Oriented Programming System, een programmeersysteem
>   waarmee je objectgeoriënteerd kunt programmeren Zie ook: OOP,
>   Objectgeoriënteerd Gevonden op
>   http://www.icer.nl/computerwoordenboek.php
>
> OOPS Object Oriented Programming System; zie OOP Gevonden op
>   http://www.ming-automatisering.nl/Definities/defin
>
> oops 1 Foutje. 2 Object Oriented Programming System. Gevonden op
>   http://www.woorden-boek.nl/woord/oops

source: http://www.encyclo.nl/begrip/OOPS (dutch)

> OOPS – Object-Oriented Programming System
>
> There may be many popular meanings for OOPS with the most popular
>   definition being that of Object-Oriented Programming System

source: http://www.auditmypc.com/oops.asp

You even got [GOOPS](http://www.gnu.org/software/goops/) and [OOPSMP](http://www.kavrakilab.org/OOPSMP/index.html) as actual implementations.